# How to put drop down list and table element at the center of page?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, html-table

I used `margin:0 auto` on div as well as table but the drop down list and table are displayed on the left side of browser (in Chrome and Firefox). In IE the table comes at the horizontal center of page but not the drop down list.

Here's the code:

```
 <div >
        <select id="ddl" onChange="showTA()" style="margin:0 auto">
            <option value="none">Select Product</option>
            <option value="ib">IB</option>
            <option value="rs">RS</option>
            <option value="bp">BP</option>
        </select>
  </div>
  <div>
        <table id="selectBox" class="tables" 
                    style="display:none; margin:0 auto;">
                <tr class="header_rows">
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>HostOS</th>
                    <th>BuildID</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>User</th>
                    <th>StartTime</th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="data_rows" ng-repeat='b in t1'>
                    <td class="tds">{{b.ID}}</td>
                    <td class="tds">{{b.HostOS}}</td>
                    <td class="tds">{{b.BuildID}}</td>
                    <td class="tds">{{b.Description}}</td>
                    <td class="tds">{{b.User}}</td>
                    <td class="tds">{{b.StartTime}}</td>
                </tr>
        </table>
  </div>
```

What I want is that the `ddl` as well as `table` should always be at the center of page even when the browser's size changes.( I need a css solution. If not possible then I'll accept Javascript as well), and I don't want to use `<center>` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `select` element is, by default, an inline element.  To center it using `margin: 0 auto`, you can change the display to block:

```
<select id="ddl" onChange="showTA()" style="display: block; margin:0 auto;">
```

Your `table` is actually centered correctly, unless there are some CSS rules in your style sheets that are causing conflicts.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/eZHQZ/

Comment: Hey! I added `display:block` to select and now it's always at the center of page. Thanks!!
But still the table shows at the left corner(in chrome and firefox) idk why.

Comment: Tables just leave margin: 0 auto;

Comment: In the fiddle, the table is centered... are there CSS style sheets attached to you web page?

Comment: Well i removed the css. So currently there's no css attached to the page.

Comment: and the display of table has to be `display:none` cuz I make it visible when BP is selected from select menu I provided through javascript.

Comment: I realize why you put `display: none` in your original code.  I took it out temporarily so that I could see that the table was indeed centered.

Comment: Are you using angular.js?

Comment: yes I'm using angularjs controller. Though all the controller does is get data from a rest call.

Answer (score 1):

Please add align property to both Div and table just like this:

```
<div align="center"></div>
<table align="center"></table>
```

This might help you.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2Pe6X/)

Comment: Adding `display: block` to the `<table>` will probably break the layout, not a good idea.  Besides, the table is  by default, a block level element.